Trigger numeric keyboard for editable <td> when doing entry from a phone
I am working on a php page from which a editable row is added to the table on button click through js. Now I just want that only numeric keyboard should be triggered for that editable s.
please help.
I have tried adding <input> inside <td> but this will create 2 input fields within td

I am a beginner to work on JS.
$(function() { // Create New Row 
  $('#add_member').click(function() { 
  if ($('tr[data-id=""]').length > 0) { 
    $('tr[data-id=""]').find('[name="name"]').focus() return false; 
  } 

  var tr = $('<tr>') 
  $('input[name="id"]').val('') 
  tr.addClass('py-1 px-2'); 
  tr.attr('data-id', ''); 
  tr.append('<td contenteditable name="round"><input type="number" style="height:80px"></input></td>')
  $('#form-tbl').append(tr) 
 
 tr.find('[name="round"]').focus() 
})


Please post code here, not as an image.

If you want to add code or info, please click the Edit link under your question, and edit it.  Comments are not a good place for code.
